# Warning message in admin panel after creating custom taxonomy and custom post type (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a custom taxonomy and a custom post type:

```
<?php

function my_custom_taxonomies() {

 register_taxonomy('block',array('static_content'), array(
   'hierarchical' => true,
   'label' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Blocks' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Block' ),
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Block',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Block',
    'new_item' => 'New Block',
    'search_items' => 'Search Block',
    'not_found' => 'No Block Found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Block found in trash',
   ),
   'query_var' => true, // enable taxonomy-specific querying
   'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'block' ), // pretty permalinks for your taxonomy?
  )
 );
}
add_action('init', 'my_custom_taxonomies', 0);

// === CUSTOM POST TYPES === //
function create_my_post_types() {
 register_post_type( 'static_content',
  array(
   'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Static Content' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Static Content' ),
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Static Content',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Static Content',
    'new_item' => 'New Static Content',
    'search_items' => 'Search Static Content',
    'not_found' => 'No Static Content found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Static Content found in trash',
   ),
   '_builtin' => false,
   'public' => true,
   'hierarchical' => false,
   'taxonomies' => array( 'static_content'),
   'supports' => array(
    'title',
    'editor',
    'excerpt'
   ),
   'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'static_content', 'with_front' => false )
  )
 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_my_post_types' );
```

But everytime I enter the dashboard I see the following message:

> ```
> Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
> ```
>
> in
>   /home/alex/www/static-wordpress/wp-admin/admin-header.php
>   on line 14

And the custom post type just says Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last item in the 'labels' arrays has a comma on it - they shouldn't. (That's just nit-picky, though).

If you remove these 2 functions from your functions.php file, does the error not appear? (i.e. have you checked that it's absolutely these 2 blocks of code causing a problem?)

Try removing the last comma and see if the error still occurs. I suspect it will, but might as well start somewhere :)

Comment: You can actually leave the last comma, it's perfectly valid to do so. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php , see information in the "Parameters" section.